# How to tell if a DbContext entity is a table or a view?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity, .net-6.0

I need to process an operation on all the tables in the database, to do this I need to be able to separate the tables from the views.

I am currently using the following code to fast fail my `foreach loop` on the tables if the current entity is a view. This approach is not finding all of the views:

```
var views = dbContext.Model
                     .GetEntityTypes()
                     .Where(e => e.ClrType.Name.Contains("View"))
                     .ToList();

if (views.Any(v => v.GetTableName() == currentTableName))
{ 
    return $"N, Is View.";
}
```

Comment: Try GetSchema : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.getschema?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0

Comment: If you depend on ClrType names then, apparently, you haven't been consistent in naming the types. As for EF, it can only know the distinction from the mapping configuration. Views can be mapped as tables and EF will never know they're views. You'll have to query the database's system views.

Comment: @GertArnold This is a database first tool we are creating to update a legacy database and bring it into the modern world. We did not name the types, all types came from the database directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by replacing my code the following:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(entityType.GetViewName()))
{
    return $"N, Is View.";
}
```